# Camada de Modelo com classes DAO

Tags: php, mvc, design-pattern, doctrine, orm

Trabalho com uma aplicação MVC que pode ser considerada grande ou pelo menos média, pois envolve centenas de funcionalidades e mais de 400 tabelas de banco de dados MySQL. Como ferramenta ORM adotamos o Doctrine através de injeção de dependências, e optamos por adotar o padrão DAO (Data Acess Object) para armazenamento de consultas para cada classe de Entidade, ou seja, cada tabela do banco tem um classe de Entidade que representa, e esta por sua vez possui uma classe DAO.

Não sei se isto é normal, mas o problema é que as classes DAO estão ficando muito grandes, em algumas já temos mais de 30 métodos onde cada um representa um tipo de consulta ou regra de negócio.

Estamos tentando criar os métodos de forma mais específica e parametrizada o possível, além disso, todas as classes DAO são filhas da classe `AbstractDAO`, que já implementa e disponibiliza métodos genéricos, como *insert*, *update*, *find*, *list*, e outros.

Vocês me sugerem alguma técnica, padrão ou ferramenta para conseguir condensar ainda mais o código, ou pelo menos organizá-lo melhor?

Exemplo de uma classe EntidadeDAO sem a implementação dos métodos:

```
<?php

/**
 * Classe de modelo da entidade EstembalagemVolume
 *
 * @author Maycon Brito
 * @since 02/09/2014
 */
class EstembalagemVolumeDAO extends ModelDAO {

    /**
     * @override
     * @return \Doctrine\Entidades\EstembalagemVolume
     */
    public function getEntidade() {
        return new Doctrine\Entidades\EstembalagemVolume();
    }

    /**
     * Busca um determinado registro a partir do lote e do pálete do mesmo.
     * 
     * @param string $lote
     * @param string $palete
     * @return 
     */
    public function findPorLotePalete($lote, $palete) {

    }

    /**
     * Consulta os registros da tabela Estembalagem_volume a partir dos parâmetros especificados
     * 
     * @param int $idEtiqueta id da etiqueta do volume
     * @param int $idCre id do cre do volume
     * @return array os registros retornados pela consulta
     */
    public function listarPorEtiquetaCRE($idEtiqueta, $idCre) {

    }

    /**
     * Retorna os objetos EstembalagemVolume e os objetos EstoqueembalagemMapa relacionados ao
     * CR e à situação especificados por parâmetro.
     * 
     * @param int $anoCr número do ano do CR
     * @param int $codigoCr número do código do CR
     * @param int $qtdeCr número da quantidade do CR
     * @param string $situacao situação dos registros de EstembalagemVolume
     * @return array o resultado da consulta
     */
    public function listarEstoqueEmbalagemMapa($anoCr, $codigoCr, $qtdeCr, $situacao) {

    }

    /**
     * Busca no banco de dados os objetos de EstoqueembalagemVolume com innerjoin com a 
     * tabela FornecedoresCR, utilizando como parâmetros de busca o id da etiqueta do
     * volume e o código do fornecedorCr (idCr)
     * 
     * @param int $idEtiqueta id da etiqueta
     * @param int $idCr id do Cr ou simplesmente o atributo código da tabela fornecedores
     * @return array o resultado da query
     */
    public function listarComFornecedoresCr($idEtiqueta, $idCr) {

    }

    /**
     * Realiza a alteração do idLocal de um determinado registro de id $idVolume no banco de dados.
     * 
     * @param int $idVolume id do volume a ser alterado
     * @param int $idLocal idLocal a ser atualizado
     * @return \EstembalagemVolumeDAO
     */
    public function alterarLocal($idVolume, $idLocal) {

    }

    /**
     * Realiza a alteração da situação de um determinado registro de id $idVolume no banco de dados.
     * 
     * @param int $idVolume id do volume a ser alterado
     * @param string $situacao nova situação a ser atualizada no registro
     * @return \EstembalagemVolumeDAO
     */
    public function alterarSituacao($idVolume, $situacao) {

    }

    /**
     * Busca os objetos EstembalagemVolume que satisfaçam os parâmetros passados e retorna
     * a número de registros encontrados
     * 
     * @param int $anoCr o ano do cr
     * @param int $codigoCr o código do cr
     * @param int $qtdeCr a quantidade do cr
     * @param string $situacao a situação dos volumes
     * @return array o resultado da consulta
     */
    public function totalVolume($anoCr, $codigoCr, $qtdeCr, $situacao) {

    }

    /**
     * Lista os objetos EstoqueembalagemVolume de um determinado CRE e Etiqueta 
     * que estejam com situação BloqueioALME ou BloqueioLCME.
     * 
     * @param int $anoCr o ano do cr a ser consultado
     * @param int $codigoCr o código do cr a ser consultado
     * @param int $qtdeCr a quantidade do cr a ser consultado
     * @param int $idEtiqueta o id da etiqueta 
     * @return array o resultado da query
     */
    public function listarComBloqueio($anoCr, $codigoCr, $qtdeCr, $idEtiqueta) {

    }

    /**
     * Consulta registros do tipo EstembalagemVolume a partir do idLocal, realizando
     * inner join com registros de FonecedoresCr, Produtos e EstoqueembalagemMapa. 
     * 
     * @param int $idLocal idLocal do registro
     * @param string $tipoCr tipo do cr da tabela fornecedores_cr
     * @return array o resultado da consulta
     */
    public function listarJoinPorLocal($idLocal, $tipoCr) {

    }

    /**
     * Consulta registros do tipo EstembalagemVolume a partir do idLocal
     * 
     * @param int $idLocal idLocal do registro
     * @return array o resultado da consulta
     */
    public function listarDadosCrPorLocal($idLocal) {

    }

    /**
     * Busca o objeto relacionado ao id especificado por parâmetro
     * 
     * @param int $id id do objeto a ser consultado
     * @return object o objeto resultante da consulta
     */
    public function get($id) {

    }

    /**
     * Busca o objeto relacionado ao id especificado por parâmetro, porém
     * nesta consulta são realizados left joins com as tabelas estembalagem_volume,
     * fornecedores_cr e produtos, que sejam relacionados ao objeto encontrado.
     * 
     * @param int $id id do objeto a ser consultado
     * @return object o objeto resultante da consulta
     */
    public function getJoin($id) {

    }

    /**
     * Consulta registros EstembalagemMapa realizando inner join com os objetos
     * EstembalagemVolume e Situacao, para um determinado Cr especificado por parâmetro.
     * 
     * @param int $anoCr o ano do cr a ser consultado
     * @param int $codigoCr o código do cr a ser consultado
     * @param int $qtdeCr a quantidade do cr a ser consultado
     * @return array o resultado da query
     */
    public function listarComEstembalagemVolume($anoCr, $codigoCr, $qtdeCr) {

    }

    /**
     * Recupera no banco de dados os objetos Estoqueembalagem com innerJoin com
     * objetos dos tipos Produtos e FornecedoresCr, sendo do mesmo idCr do especificado
     * por parâmetro.
     * 
     * @param int $idCr id do Cr de fornecedores_cr
     * @return array o resultado da query
     */
    public function listarComProdutosFornecedoresCR($idCr) {

    }

    /**
     * Recupera no banco de dados os objetos Estoqueembalagem com innerJoin com
     * objetos dos tipos EstembalagemVolume, sendo do mesmo volume, anocr, codigocr, qtdecr do especificado
     * por parâmetro.
     * 
     * @param int $anoCr o ano do cr a ser consultado
     * @param int $codigoCr o código do cr a ser consultado
     * @param int $qtdeCr a quantidade do cr a ser consultado
     * @return array o resultado da query
     */
    public function listarComEstEmbalagemVolume($anoCr, $codigoCr, $qtdeCr, $idEtiqueta) {

    }

    /**
     * Recupera no banco de dados os objetos Estoqueembalagem com innerJoin com
     * objetos dos tipos Produtos e Funcionarios, sendo do mesmo codigoproduto, responsável e empresaresponsavel
     * com leftjoin com objetos dos tipos Observacaoembalagem, sendo do mesmo codigomovimento
     * por parâmetro.
     * 
     * @return array o resultado da query
     */
    public function listarComProdutosFuncionariosObservacaoEmbalagem() {

    }

    /**
     * Realiza a alteração do tipo movimento de um determinado registro de id $idVolume no banco de dados.
     * 
     * @param int $idVolume id do volume(codigomovimento) a ser alterado
     * @param string $tipomovimento novo tipo movimento a ser atualizada no registro
     * @return \EstoqueEmbalagem
     */
    public function alterarTipoMovimento($idVolume, $tipomovimento) {

    }

    /**
     * Realiza a alteracao do crencerrado de um registro de $anocr, $codigocr, $qtdecr, $cod_produto no banco de dados
     * 
     * @param int $anoCr ano do Cr da embalagem a ser alterada
     * @param int $codigoCr codigo do Cr da embalagem a ser alterada
     * @param int $qtdeCr quantidade do Cr da embalagem a ser alterada
     * @param int $codigoProduto codigo da embalagem a ser alterada
     * @return \EstoqueEmbalagem
     */
    public function alterarCrEncerrado($anoCr, $codigoCr, $qtdeCr, $codigoProduto) {

    }

    /**
     * Realiza a alteração da data movimento de um determinado registro de id $idVolume no banco de dados.
     * 
     * @param int $idVolume id do volume a ser alterado
     * @param date $datamovimento nova data movimento a ser atualizada no registro
     * @return \EstoqueEmbalagem
     */
    public function alterarDataMovimento($idVolume, $datamovimento) {

    }

    /**
     * Recupera no banco de dados os objetos Estoqueembalagem 
     * 
     * @param int $anoCr o ano do cr a ser consultado
     * @param int $codigoCr o código do cr a ser consultado
     * @param int $qtdeCr a quantidade do cr a ser consultado
     * @param int $numVolume o número do volume a ser consultado
     * 
     * @return array o resultado da query
     */
    public function listaIdEstoqueEmbalagem($anoCr, $codigoCr, $qtdeCr, $numVolume) {

    }

}
```

Comment: Você poderia postar ao menos uma dessas classes que você considera grande?

Comment: @BrunoAugusto vou postar uma dessas DAO, mas vou omitir a regra de negócio, ou seja, postarei somente a declaração dos métodos.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que em relação à DAO está ok.
Tente implementar mais camadas de negócios BL ( Business Layers ) 
Camadas de entidades de domínio.
Alguns helpers se precisar de códigos e métodos duplicados.

Evite utilizar muitas tecnologias e ddl's de terceiros.

Lembre-se sempre.
Menos é mais!
Quanto menos você escrever( desde que seja com qualidade ), mais fácil de manutenção seu código será.

Comment: Obrigado @Johnathan. Essas BL's seriam criadas em outras classes na camada de modelo? Ou seja, a camada de modelo além das classes de Entidades e EntidadesDAO também teria EntidadeBL?